# rvm cant install ruby 2.0.0-p451

Tags: system-installation, ruby, rvm

Hello I am trying to install ruby 2.0.0-p451 via:

```
rvm install ruby 2.0.0-p451
```

and I get the following error:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p451.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p451 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p451, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.bz2.part: Permission 
Warning: denied
  0 10.2M    0   941    0     0    585      0  5:05:34  0:00:01  5:05:33   585
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 941)
There was an error(23).
Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.bz2.part: Permission 
Warning: denied
  0 10.2M    0  1167    0     0    613      0  4:51:36  0:00:01  4:51:35   613
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1167)
There was an error(23).
Failed download
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

I have rvm but for some reason I can't download the version of ruby that I need.  Thanks anyone who knows what I need to do and I have tried using sudo but that is not a rvm command apparently.

```
rvm get head


Downloading https://get.rvm.io
bash: line 709: /usr/local/rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied
Could not update RVM, get some help at #rvm IRC channel at freenode servers.
```

Thanks for trying to help, I have ran every suggestion but nothing seems to be working=( Thanks again though and I hope we can figure it out soon!

Comment: Do I need to do this all in root via: sudo su? I heard this can be bad to do but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My super mean secure network at home was blocking the download! Thanks so much for all the help! Can't believe it was just my internet connection!  All I had to do was run down the street to the local diner and use their wi-fi. Thanks public wi-fi for spreading across the world;)

Answer (score 0):

You can install RVM and Ruby using using following commands.

Installing the stable release version of RVM:

```
   \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

To get the latest development state:

```
   \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Installing a specific version:

```
  \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --version latest
  \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --branch [owner/][repo]
```

Install RVM stable with ruby:

```
   \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

There are three different ways to install and configure RVM.

- Single-User installations (recommended) - For an isolated install within a user's $HOME, not for root.
- Multi-User installations - For server administrators - For an installation usable by all users on the system - Please note that Single-User supersedes Multi-User. This also used to be called the System-Wide Install. Using this type of installation.
- Mixed mode installations - For an installation usable by all users on the system - with isolated rubies/gemsets within a user's $HOME. Installation instructions are exactly the same as for Multi-User installations, the difference is in users environment.

Comment: bash: line 709: /usr/local/rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied

Comment: is what I get when doing these commands

Comment: @ZachyBear What **exact** commands did you enter?

Comment: \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby